# What to do this type of data

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I have plots of feature vs target values as

[image]

and

[image]

And many more. I have used Tree based models and able to get high accuracy but not able to improve further. Any suggestion ? almost every feature is like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have more than one target value for a specific value of the feature and because the Y values are have quite a large range I guess the nueral network finds it hard to converge. Try to [normalize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/normalize-data) the target values so that it has zero mean and unit variance and then try to use any of the regression models like logistic regression, A CNN with a squared error to get a prediction. After that plot the [ROC-AUC](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5) to determine the dominant regressor.

Comment: I was using Decision Trees